# Why does ASP.NET dangerous request validation work this way?

Tags: asp.net, validation, dangerous-request

Can anyone point me in the right direction with the following question.

The default "Dangerous Request" validation in ASP.NET prohibits inputs like

```
"<p", "<p>" or "<script>"
```

but at the same time allows inputs like

```
"<%script>" or "<.script>"
```

What is the rational here?

Answer (score 2):

> `<p`, `<p>` or `<script>`

These look like HTML/XML tags.

> `<%script>` or `<.script>`

but these do not.

And the validation is trying to stop cross site scripting, eg. submitting a field containing:

```
<script>alert("You're powned!")</script>
```

(except truly malicious) and when you just write that text back to the user without being careful to encode correctly the user has just injected code into your website.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I am kinda more asking a question why is "<p" etc. considered dangerous but "<%script not"? What prevents tag "<%script" to be exploited in the same way? What is the practical reason here? I haven't tried to dig down into the topic yet.

Comment: @lekso Because your browser does not consider `<%script` to start a script element (unless it is *very* broken): for a start `%` is not a valid character in an element name.

Comment: I'll give a reason for asking: we have this being flagged as a penetration testing issue. I'm trying to asses the risks

Comment: @lekso In that case ask the pen testers how `<%script>` is exploitable.

Comment: We asked. He said that he didn't find the way to exploit it, but this can be a vulnerability for future attacks

Comment: @lekso On that logic everything that isn't precisely valid data "could be a vulnerability for future attacks": you can either use the tools provided or write your own. Perhaps time to escalate this as (1) it is not currently a vulnerability, (2) it will cost $$$ to block something that may never be a thread. Security is always a compromise between usability, cost and risk..